# CKEditor in WP 4.72 and CiviCRM 4.7.16 strips inline CSS for CiviMAIL

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor

The editor strips the inline CSS when composing the emails but seems to re-append when sent. My Comms users are freaking out that they can't check their work before it goes out.

I recently held off upgrading 4.7.13 because I get crazy bugs every time I update. This happened after I did what I hate doing :)

Comment: For further reference I've installed TinyMCE and it also strips the inline CSS. Is it further up the Civi chain?

Comment: The fullpage switch for the CiviMail component makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be by design.

The stripping of head tags has killed my designed templates and I have had to roll back to 4.7.13 until a solution can be found.

I get a little frustrated with undocumented features creeping into minor updates.